# How to reopen a closed Gitlab Projectissue with the python gitlab module

Tags: python, api, gitlab

Trying to automate reopening a bunch of issues on a kanban board in Gitlab does not seem to be working as expected. I can edit pretty much everything else: labels, title, description, due date and so on, but changing the state from 'closed' to 'opened' is not doing anything.
Funny enough the save() method, takes some time to complete and is not throwing any error (but it does when I try to update an issue without having changed anything)

```
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(URL, private_token=TOKEN, api_version = 4)
gl.auth()
Project = gl.projects.get(project_id, lazy=True)
editable_issue = Project.issues.get(issue_id)
```

I use this to instantiate the gitlab object

This works:

```
editable_issue.labels.append('some label')
editable_issue.save()

editable_issue.title = title + '\n' + 'edited.'
editable_issue.save()
```

But this doesn't:

```
editable_issue.state = 'opened'
editable_issue.save()
```

I have also tried changing several fields, like so:

```
editable_issue.state = 'opened'
editable_issue.closed_at = None
editable_issue.save()
```

But, albeit I receive no error, the task is not being updated.

Is there something I'm overlooking ?

**edit**
Oh yes, I forgot to mention that the documentation seems to be mentioning `state_event` as a method, while my object does not know of such a method.
Is this method only there when a projectissue is being created by the api, perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation, you must set the `state_event` attribute, then save. This attribute won't exist at first -- you must create it.

```
issue.state_event = 'reopen'
issue.save()
```

Modifying `state` or `closed_at` won't work because the [issues edit API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#edit-issue) doesn't accept `state` or `closed_at` parameters.

(this is also why `state_event` doesn't exist on the object at first, because the issue detail API doesn't include `state_event` in its response -- all the attributes are set dynamically by the response JSON)

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. I will accept your answer as soon as I did. Thx !